# Returning a tree structure from lines to columns with oracle sql and a recursive join

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Thank you community member for your help again upfront.

[image]

Edit: There is a mistake in the picture. It shouldn't be ItemC but ItemB.

I have following data calling it the table tree:

| TreeID | ItemID | ParentItemID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 6 | 5 |
| 7 | 7 | 6 |
| 8 | 7 | 4 |

and table itemnames

| ItemID | ItemName |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | (null) |
| 1 | RootFileA |
| 2 | FileA |
| 3 | ItemA |
| 4 | FileB |
| 5 | RootFileB |
| 6 | FileC |
| 7 | ItemB |

ItemID and TreeID do not always match as an item can be used multiple times.

csv format:

```
TreeID,ItemID,ParentItemID
1,1,0
2,2,1
3,3,2
4,4,2
5,5,0
6,6,5
7,7,6
8,7,7

ItemID,ItemName
0,(null)
1,RootFileA
2,FileA
3,ItemA
4,FileB
5,RootFileB
6,FileC
7,ItemB
```

I'm searching a solution for x-nodes/levels in the tree. So it probably needs to be a recursive/CTE statement.

The solution should look like:

| FileNodeX | ... | FileNode2 | FileNode1 | ItemNode | ItemID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .... | .... | ..... | ...... | ..... | ...... |

or

| ItemID | ItemNode | FileNode1 | FileNode2 | ... | FileNodeX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .... | ... | ..... | ...... | ..... | ...... |

Giving a table for our example like this:

| ItemName4 | ItemName3 | ItemName2 | ItemName1 | ItemID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (null) | RootFileA | FileA | ItemA | 4 |
| RootfileA | FileA | FileB | ItemB | 7 |
| (null) | RootFileB | FileC | ItemB | 7 |

The IDs for items probably need to be in one column as I want to join those with a table holding more information for them.

Has someone an idea on how to achieve something like a recursive table join?

Comment: SQL result set should have fixed structure. You cannot dynamically generate columns depending on the data, you need dynamic SQL for this

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I want to run the query in Excel to extract data with PowerQuery, so I probably have to find a workaround.

Comment: If you are able to use PQ, then it would be much easier to use the answer as a base for data set to limit by root element if required or use plain table for all the data and then use PowerQuery to generate dynamically wide table

Answer (score 0):

For a tree-depth of four items you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT treeid AS treeid,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT i.itemid AS itemid,
         MAX(LEVEL) OVER(PARTITION BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT treeid) - LEVEL + 1 AS lvl,
         i.itemname
  FROM   tree t
         INNER JOIN itemnames i
         ON (t.itemId = i.itemId)
  CONNECT BY t.itemId = PRIOR t.parentItemId
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(itemname)
  FOR lvl IN (
    4 AS itemname1,
    3 AS itemname2,
    2 AS itemname3,
    1 AS itemname4
  )
)
ORDER BY treeid
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tree (TreeID, ItemID, ParentItemID) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 5, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 6, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 7, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 7, 4 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE itemnames (ItemID, ItemName) AS
SELECT 0, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'RootFileA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'FileA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'ItemA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'FileB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'RootFileB' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'FileC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'ItemB' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| TREEID | ITEMID | ITEMNAME1 | ITEMNAME2 | ITEMNAME3 | ITEMNAME4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | *null* | *null* | *null* | RootFileA |
| 2 | 2 | *null* | *null* | FileA | RootFileA |
| 3 | 3 | *null* | ItemA | FileA | RootFileA |
| 4 | 4 | *null* | FileB | FileA | RootFileA |
| 5 | 5 | *null* | *null* | *null* | RootFileB |
| 6 | 6 | *null* | *null* | FileC | RootFileB |
| 7 | 7 | *null* | ItemB | FileC | RootFileB |
| 8 | 7 | ItemB | FileB | FileA | RootFileA |

If you want to increase (or decrease) the item depth then increase (decrease) the number of items in the `IN` clause of the `PIVOT`.

---

If you have a dynamic depth then output the data as rows, not columns, using only the inner query:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT treeid AS treeid,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT i.itemid AS itemid,
       MAX(LEVEL) OVER(PARTITION BY CONNECT_BY_ROOT treeid) - LEVEL + 1 AS lvl,
       i.itemname
FROM   tree t
       INNER JOIN itemnames i
       ON (t.itemId = i.itemId)
CONNECT BY t.itemId = PRIOR t.parentItemId;
```

Which outputs:

| TREEID | ITEMID | LVL | ITEMNAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | RootFileA |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | FileA |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | RootFileA |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | ItemA |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | FileA |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | RootFileA |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | FileB |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | FileA |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | RootFileA |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | RootFileB |
| 6 | 6 | 2 | FileC |
| 6 | 6 | 1 | RootFileB |
| 7 | 7 | 2 | FileC |
| 7 | 7 | 3 | ItemB |
| 7 | 7 | 1 | RootFileB |
| 8 | 7 | 1 | RootFileA |
| 8 | 7 | 3 | FileB |
| 8 | 7 | 4 | ItemB |
| 8 | 7 | 2 | FileA |

Then you can pivot the rows to columns in a third-party language (i.e. Java, C, C#, Python, etc.) as Oracle does not natively support dynamic pivots. (You could generate dynamic SQL to perform the pivot but it is more cumbersome, difficult to maintain and this presentational issue is generally better handled in a third-party language than in SQL.)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7HDJM6L1)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. If I would know exactly the number of columns or a maximum x then I also could simply go for x joins. Even though your answer looks a bit cleaner. What makes the challenge is the problem that I don't have a fixed number.

Comment: @Hisager SQL requires you to have a fixed number of pre-defined columns. If you have a dynamic number of columns then you either need to (1) dynamically generate SQL statements with different number of columns; or (2) use a fixed output in SQL and pivot the result set from rows to columns in a third-party language (Java, C, PHP, Python, etc.). Typically, option 2 is used (because option 1 is difficult to maintain and more cumbersome to use).

Comment: I tried your code with my real data sets but I'm getting the error message:
ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data

Do you may have an idea why? I also added a 0, null record via UNION ALL for itemnames.

Comment: @Hisager Your data has a loop in it. If you connect `0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 1` then you will get into an infinite loop. Either fix your data so it only contains trees (and not cycles) or use `COLLECT BY NOCYCLE ...` to stop looping when it detects a cycle.